# Ruby on Rails Routing Error for a link to a website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am studying Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.
My app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb contains a link to a website www.railstutorial.org
Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Help</h1>
  <p>
    Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the 
    <a href=“http://www.railstutorial.org/#help”>Rails Tutorial help section</a>
  </p>
```

but I get the error `No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/%E2%80%9Chttp:/www.railstutorial.org"`

Howe does get function in routes.rb work for a link? is it supposed to be something like

```
get 'static_pages/wwww.railstutorial.org' ?
```

Comment: Have you tried using embedded ruby for the link instead? You dont need to specify an external link in your routes.rb file btw.

Comment: You're using "smart quotes" (`“` and `”`) rather than normal double quotes (`"`). HTML uses plain old ASCII quotes for attributes.

Comment: Hi Mint perhaps you wan't a link_to     http://www.railstutorial.org/#help.?

Answer (score 0):

You need a controller called `StaticPagesController` with a method in it. Then name doesn't matter. Then in the routes files it would be `get "static_pages/wwww.railstutorial.org", to: "static_pages#method_name"`
For this the controller would look like:

```
class StaticPagesController < ActionController
  def method_name
  end
end
```

Also note, You'll need a corresponding view in the static_pages views folder called `method_name`

Comment: No, as mentioned in the comments by @mu is too short, the error is using `“http://www.railstutorial.org/#help”` the smart quotes, rather than the standard `"http://www.railstutorial.org/#help"` quotes. No need for another controller

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any route configuration at all. It's a simple HTML a tag. Read more about HTML a tag in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp